# How to get the value of an html textbox placed in a repeater, through ASP.NET code-behind?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

I have a repeater, which contains a text box (html) in the ItemTemplate.

I cannot create an asp textbox, as the text box in question needs to be accessed through jQuery for user manipulation of the text box.

Once the user is done, an asp button is pressed in the respective repeater row, and I would like to get the value which the user has entered into the text box, through the code behind (c#).

Could anyone tell me if this is at all possible? If so, could some code be suggested?

Otherwise, any non-AJAX alternatives?

Comment: It's kind of hard to tell what you're after here. Do you intend to submit the value of the TextBox to an AJAX function somewhere or to the page that your Repeater is on?

Comment: @jwiscarson Think of it as a form - the user enters data into the html textbox, and when pressing a button, this data must be placed into a database. Without delving into detail, an html textbox must be used by force, and there can be no AJAX. Hence, my C# code behind must get the data which the user has input into the text box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no issue with referencing asp.net components in jQuery. A couple of things to know about this:

1. The item will an have id that includes the ID value that you originally gave the control. Using the current encoding scheme (which I cannot imaging Microsoft changing significantly), `<asp:TextBox ID="txtBox" runat="server" />` becomes `<input id="...._txtBox" name="...$txtBox" />` in the HTML. A jQuery selector like: `$(input[id$=txtBox])` will find it.
2. Because the asp controls eventually resolve to good-old HTML form elements, you treat them exactly like an HTML element you created directly. In this case, you enable/disable it using the pseudo-class disabled.
3. I learned much of this by viewing the generated source for my web pages and seeing what was happening. I like FireFox with the Web Developer's Toolbar and its View Generated Source command.

Comment: I have tried this, but how exactly do i get the text? I cannot access the 'text' attribute since it is an html element.

Comment: My bad. Since you are in a repeater, you are going to have multiple controls, one for each item. I have never done this, but you may have id issues. However, you can access server controls using jQuery, they have IDs just like everything else. Use a selector that catches the control you want, and it will work just fine.

Comment: Unfortunately I need to do it vice versa, however. I need to access an html control through C#

Comment: What I'm saying is that you can use an asp control and still use jQuery. You said "I cannot create an asp textbox, as the text box in question needs to be accessed through jQuery" which is not true.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean - sorry about that, misunderstood you. Unfortunately I started off with an asp control, but ran into problems due to the nature of the repeater, and had to switch to html controls for it to work.

Comment: My main problem was that I needed to set the text box to be enabled/disabled at times with jquery. And since it is an asp element, I was unable to do so. Is it possible?

Comment: yes. you just need to develop a selector that catches the item in question. We do it all the time here.

Comment: Do you think you could kindly link me to an explanation regarding this topic? :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4703/discussion-between-drdwilcox-and-sean)

Comment: @drdwilcox, can you edit this answer to include some of the details you discussed with Sean in chat?

Answer (score 1):

This should do it. Let me know if you want/need any further explanation.

put this in your aspx page:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<asp:Repeater ID="rptHtmlTag" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <input id="htmlTextBox" runat="server" />
        </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
</div>
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
</form>
```

put this in your code-behind:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    this.rptHtmlTag.ItemDataBound += new RepeaterItemEventHandler(rptHtmlTag_ItemDataBound);
    this.btnSubmit.Click += new EventHandler(btnSubmit_Click);
    base.OnInit(e);
}

void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (RepeaterItem item in this.rptHtmlTag.Items)
    {
        HtmlInputText htmlTextBox = (HtmlInputText)item.FindControl("htmlTextBox");
        string THIS_IS_YOUR_VALUE = htmlTextBox.Value;
    }
}

void rptHtmlTag_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        HtmlInputText htmlTextBox = (HtmlInputText )e.Item.FindControl("htmlTextBox");
        htmlTextBox.Value = String.Concat("Some Value - Index", e.Item.ItemIndex);
    }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        List<int> repeaterPopulator = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
        this.rptHtmlTag.DataSource = repeaterPopulator;
        this.rptHtmlTag.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! It looks to be exactly what I was looking for. I'm going to try going for 'drdwilcox's suggested approach. Otherwise, I'll try this out.

Comment: I agree with @drdwilcox. That is a better solution :) btw, if you are using .net 4, you can override the cumbersome .net id and  set the id to whatever you want. [Here's a link if it interests you](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2009/Nov/07/ClientIDMode-in-ASPNET-40)